# How to query a menu table params value in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

First of all I'm using the K2 component and my Menu Item Type is set to categories (itemlist).

Now I have the K2Filter search module which I using to search by categories. But when it displays the category searched, it doesn't change the Itemid. So I trying to get it to do that.

Luckily, the module does get the category id (of course).

So I'm trying to add a bit of code that will use the category id to query the menu table to find the proper menu id in order to set the Itemid to the correct value.

The only catch is that the category id is stored in the params of the menu item. Which looks like this:

```
"categories":["24"],"singleCatOrdering":"","menu-anchor_title":"",etc...
```

SO I was thinking, I'll get category variable, then use it to query the menu table and get the id. But I can't seem to pull the value of the catagories in the params.

```
SELECT id FROM #__menu where $the_params_categories_value= $catid;
```

Maybe I'm going about this wrong, I really open to suggestion. Anyone?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the issue. But, are each of the K2 categories being searched associated with a menu item individually? Maybe another way to ask is what Itemid are you trying to set?

Comment: @betweenbrain - Yes, they are all associated to menu item. And I'm trying to set the Itemid in URL, because the problem witht the module is that it does do that, and I'm tring to add that feeature to it.